# javascript cannot call global variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I am having a situation that I created a global variable in JavaScript and I assigned it in an `addEventListener`. However, when I want to call the variable in another if case, it says it is `undefined`
**Here is my code in JavaScript**

```
let userID; // the global variable (btw I have tried both let and var)

// Check if this page is the login in page
if (fileName[0] === "index.html") {
    var signIn = document.getElementById("signInbnt");

    // Sign in 
    signIn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        let email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        let pwd = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
        userID = email // Assign the variable
        console.log(userID)// It work as my expectation (i.e. "test@gmail.com")

        signInFunction(email, pwd);
    });
    // End of Sign in

} else if (fileName[0] === "system.html") {
    console.log(userID) // It shows "undefined"
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
        if (user) {
            let uid = user.uid;
            getUserName(uid);
        }
    });
}
```

For your reference here is the code of the `signInFunction`

```
function signInFunction(email, pwd) {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pwd).then(function () {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
            if (user) {
                db.ref('users/' + user.uid + '/name').once('value').then(
                    name => {
                        passwordUpdate(name.val(), pwd)
                    }
                )
            }
        });
        document.location.href = 'system.html';
    }).catch(function (error) {
        if (error != null) {
            // Get Error Message
            let errorMessage = error.message;

            // Make The Horizontal Rule Be Visible
            document.getElementById("login-hr").style.visibility = "visible";

            // Load Error Message
            document.getElementById("login-error").innerHTML = errorMessage;

            // Make The Error Message Be Visible
            document.getElementById("login-error").style.visibility = "visible";

        }
    })
}
```

Could any tell me **why** I cannot call the global variable and how I can **solve** it. Thank you very much

Comment: global variables should be avoided. why do you want one?

Comment: I want one is because I am using the ```firebase reatime database``` and I want to set the email become the one of the node of the data. To access to the data, it requires a correct path. Therefore, I need to save the email with a global variable in order to form a correct path to access the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it returns `undefined` because when you first declared `userID` it doesnt have any value yet. it will only have a value when your code runs the first `if-statement`, which is the `email`. however, if your code skips the first `if-statement` because it hasnt met the set condition, it will run the `else-if statement` which do not assign anything to your `userID` variable. thats why when you log it into the console it returns `undefined`

Comment: I see,  I also tried to split it with 2 ```if-statement``` but it still not work. Besides, How can I do to assign the variable in order to pass the value?

Comment: to pass the userID value, upon successful login you need to store it in a session. you can refer to this documentation https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp

Answer (score 1):

```js
let userID; // the global variable (btw I have tried both let and var)

// now userID === 'undefined
// Check if this page is the login in page
if (fileName[0] === "index.html") {
    ...

    // Sign in 
    signIn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        ...
        userID = email // Assign the variable
        // userId ===  email
        ...
    });
    // End of Sign in

} else if (fileName[0] === "system.html") {
    console.log(userID) // It shows "undefined"
    // u didn't assign value to userID, so it still undefined
    
}
```